# .NET JwtBearer Authentication - Use Access Token to get ID Token

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, openid-connect

I have a .NET 6 API that uses `AddJwtBearer` to accept a JWT Access Token from the caller. The API is able to successfully accept/parse the access token, however I need to get additional user info from the OpenID Connect Authorization server. Is there no built-in way to do this with .NET 6 using the existing access token? I cannot include the additional info directly in the access token for policy reasons.

I've searched but not found anything so far.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
      .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, jwt =>
       {
         jwt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
           {
             ValidateIssuer = true,
                       ....
            ;
                
         });
```

Answer (score 2):

JwtBearer provides various places where you can add your own event handling, the following picture I made outlines what is available:

[image]

In code, you can access these event handlers like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    opt.Audience = "payment";      
    opt.Authority = "https://localhost:6001";

    opt.Events.OnMessageReceived = context =>
    {
        // When Authenticate is called
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    opt.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
    {
        // When exceptions are thrown during request processing (invalid token...)
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    opt.Events.OnChallenge = context =>
    {
        // Invoked before a challenge is sent back to the caller.
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    opt.Events.OnForbidden = context =>
    {
        // Invoked if Authorization fails and results in a Forbidden response
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    opt.Events.OnTokenValidated = context =>
    {
        // Token has passed validation and a ClaimsIdentity has been generated.
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

In your case you can use the TokenValidated event to request additional user info.

If you need to troubleshoot JwtBearer, then I have a blog post about it here
https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: I’m aware of the various events. I am trying to avoid making a separate API call to the user info endpoint every time an access token is passed. Is there a strategy to persist user info across calls to minimize going back to the user info API every time?

Comment: Yes, you can actually apply caching in JWT Bearer to reduce the need to go back for the user details on every request. See this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSnjrlmTdnE

Comment: Ok, I can figure the caching part out. Is there no streamlined way of making the API call to the user info endpoint though? Possibly through the BackchannelHttpHandler that already has some info about the OIDC endpoints?

Comment: Don't think there is any built in support for that in JwtBearer. Take a look a the token introspection helper library here https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/introspection.html